# Вытянуть JSON из текста на powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Есть задачка, вытащить JSON структуру на powershell, ffmpeg выводит в консоль в куче консольного вывода структуру в JSON, вот хотелось бы как то, может regexp'ом вытащить JSON и скормить его ConvertFrom-Json.
Собственно помощь нужна с самой регуляркой, вот пример вывода консоли

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2010-10-21T09:00:00.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf56.22.100
  Duration: 00:05:30.00, start: 0.040000, bitrate: 8550 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 7010 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-10-21T09:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-10-21T09:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to 'null':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-10-21T09:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 wrapped_avframe
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16le, 192000 Hz, stereo, s16, 6144 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-10-21T09:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 pcm_s16le
[null @ 000001dc77acc1c0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 8348 >= 8348
frame= 8350 fps=511 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=20.4x
video:4371kB audio:250500kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[Parsed_loudnorm_0 @ 000001dc77cbcf80]
{
        "input_i" : "-18.02",
        "input_tp" : "-8.80",
        "input_lra" : "5.10",
        "input_thresh" : "-28.35",
        "output_i" : "-23.36",
        "output_tp" : "-9.31",
        "output_lra" : "4.80",
        "output_thresh" : "-33.62",
        "normalization_type" : "dynamic",
        "target_offset" : "0.36"
}
```

Comment: Покажите сам текст

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7708373/5045688) советуют использовать ffprobe.

Comment: ffprobe неумеет того что надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенаправьте вывод запускаемого приложения в переменную и используйте ее для фильтрации нужных данных с помощью регулярных выражений.

На примере приложения `ping`:

```
$Ping = ping localhost -4 -n 1
```

Содержимое `$Ping`:

```
PS C:\> $Ping

Обмен пакетами с localhost [127.0.0.1] с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 127.0.0.1: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=128

Статистика Ping для 127.0.0.1:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 1, получено = 1, потеряно = 0
    (0% потерь)
Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:
    Минимальное = 0мсек, Максимальное = 0 мсек, Среднее = 0 мсек
```

Фильтруем вывод используя регулярные выражения:

```
PS C:\> $Ping -match '.+TTL.+'
Ответ от 127.0.0.1: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=128
```

Comment: Вопрос наверное больше был про саму регулярку

Comment: Собственно попробовал регулярку \{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\} , но как я понял PS не поддерживает (?R) поэтому заменил на + , получилось '\{(?:[^{}]+)*\}', уж незнаю насколько я правильно сделал но на regex101 всё работает верно, однако когда я делаю $err = $stderr -match '\{(?:[^{}]+)*\}' , и через Write-Host "$out" получаю в консоле true ,а не сам текст, что я делаю не так?

Comment: @vnn198, после сравнения `-match` используйте автоматическую переменную `$Matches` в ней будет подходящий условиям фрагмент строки. `$MyOutput -match  '\{(?:[^{}]+)*\}'
$Matches.Values`

Comment: Спасибо, а то я вытащил данные другой команды, в итоге получилось так $json = ($stderr | Select-String -Pattern "\{(?:[^{}]+)*\}").Matches | ConvertFrom-Json